# In a Layout container, how do I know if a key has been pressed?

Tags: python, gtk

My problem is this: in a Python script I create a window with this code:

```
class Layout(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Ricerca partite")
        self.connect("key-press-event",self.GetKeypress)
        self.set_default_size(265, 437)
        self.move(700,300)

    # other instructions
```

If one of the " + ", " - " or "Return" keys has been pressed, I must perform the corresponding actions, otherwise nothing. 
How do I check if one of the keys has been pressed? How should the "GetKeypress()" function be written?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this(assuming you have imported `gtk` and `gdk`):

```
def GetKeypress(self,event):
    keyval_name = gtk.gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval)
    if keyval_name == '+' or keyval_name == '-' or keyval_name == 'Return':
        #continue your code here
```

I think though that since you want to perform a corresponding action *after* a key has been pressed then you should change `self.connect("key-press-event",self.GetKeypress)` to 
`self.connect("key-release-event",self.GetKeypress)`.

You can find more info on the matter in the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gdkkeymap.html#function-gdk--keyval-name).

Comment: The import of the Gdk module is successful. I use Python 3.6 and I have to import Gdk and not gdk.

But the execution of the command "keyval_name = Gtk.gdk.keyval_name (event.keyval)" causes the error:

  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gi/overrides/__init__.py", line 39, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._introspection_module, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gi/module.py", line 137, in __getattr__
    self.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'gdk'

I tried with gdk and Gdk
Where is the problem?

Comment: There seems to be some problem with your imports that you need to figure out. Have you imported gtk? I had to import the following modules: `import gtk`, `import gtk.gdk`, `import gobject`, `import pygtk`.

Comment: The OP is using gtk3 (`from gi.repository import Gtk`), while your answer is using the outdated gtk2 (`import gtk`).

Comment: @Ave You have to use `from gi.repository import Gdk` and `keyval_name = Gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval)`.

Comment: @aran-Fey import are ok, but now the error is:   File "myFile.py", line 298, in GetKeypress
    keyval_name = Gdk.keyval_name(event.keyval)
AttributeError: 'Layout' object has no attribute 'keyval'

Comment: No suggestions? Help me please!

Comment: There's been some sort of mixup with your imports. Have you tried looking up that specific error?